# Update two fields at the same time syntax using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

The below code is giving errors, I may have got the syntax wrong and I do not know where. The error is: ``` near '(``last_online``) VALUE ('now()) WHERE (users.id = 55)' at line 1 ```.

The PHP code:

```
   <?php 
include 'dbc.php';
session_start();
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$sql_insert1 = "UPDATE `users` SET (`last_online`)
            VALUES
            ('now()) WHERE (users.id = $id)";

mysql_query($sql_insert1) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());
$sql_insert2 = "UPDATE `users` SET (`users_ip`)
            VALUES
            ('$user_ip') WHERE (users.id = $id)";

mysql_query($sql_insert2) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement is:

```
UPDATE table
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
```

Thus, you should use the following instead to update both fields in a single statement:

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `last_online` = now(),
    `users_ip` = '$user_ip'
WHERE (users.id = $id)
```

The `VALUES` keyword is used in the [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) statement.

Comment: now i get this error..   '(`last_online`) = now() WHERE (users.id = 55)' at line 1

Comment: Are you wrapping the `last_online` field with parenthesis? Don't do it, just use `last_online` = now()

Comment: thanks you i solved with this code <?php 
//include 'dbc.php';
//session_start();
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];


$sql_insert1 = "UPDATE `users` 
SET `last_online` = now(),
    `users_ip` = '$user_ip'
WHERE (users.id = $id)
";
mysql_query($sql_insert1) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());

?>